# Excel VBA: Using cell content in web search

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to writing VBA macros. I have written a simple macro to scrape data from an website search. I want to loop the search based on the cell content in a tab "sheet1". The search runs fine, but doesn't seem to use the cell content. I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working properly. Your help would be appreciated

```
  Sub Get_internet_data()
       For x = 1 To 3
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        MySearch = "URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?144=-1&144=-1&search=1&sidebar=1&cid=5000&rptpath=5000-"
    MySearch = Cells(x, 1)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?MySearch", Destination:=Range("$C$6"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Next x
   End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `"URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?MySearch"` to `"URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?" & MySearch`

Answer (score 0):

`MySear‌​ch` is a variable that contains a certain string, but here you're treating it as if it were the actual literal text "MySearch", meaning you're doing a search for the word "MySearch", which clearly isn't what you want.

```
"URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?MySear‌​ch" 
'                                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

To properly concatenate the string you need change this to

```
"URL;http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categoryattributesearchresults.aspx?" & MySearch
'                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```